Generate the pitched roof from any shape of the border curve
I am creating a large surrounding content for the apartment project in Canada and want to use Blender geometry nodes to generate the pitched roof model from the floors' border shape.

I want to generate the roofs for multiple floor shapes with random height and slope. The floor shapes were imported from Revit, so they are not quad meshes.

This is the way the ridge roof was created by the intersection edges between the planes cut through the border edge by slope vale (angle in red). Hope this may help us find suitable notes.

And this is the node of a simple shape. I could not get the ridge roof as the roof model reference. You can take a look at the attached blender file.

Have any idea on how to address this?
This will speed up my workflow on large-scale projects.


The roof reference shows a roof built by architectural decision, not just a simple automated process. By which factors should the node setup "decide" if some border edges are forming a pyramid shape with not a singular point but a ridge at the top, while the other border edges are just creating a roof with triangular cross-section leaving the sides open? Do you have any algorithms calculating when to use which? If you have no modus operandi for that, you have to make individual nodetrees for each floor shape, which is probably not much quicker than just doing it manually.

The roof reference was created in Revit, which allows you to set the slope and the edge you want to apply this value. And it works with the single closed boundaries only.
So I wonder if we have the same way of generating that in the geometry node. The selected edge to apply the slope can be assigned by attributes in Edit Mode but it is hard for me to get the roof ridges.

Just because there is software that can do that, this does not necessarily mean this can be done with an easy nodetree setup. I don't know how complex the programming is behind this functionality in Revit. As I said, do you have any kind of modus operandi, any building rules or instructions? You wrote "this is the node of a simple shape" - if we do not know how complex the shapes can be and even if, how the result should look like, how are we supposed to find a solution?

If I take just these four examples, the basic shape of all buildings is a T-shape in my opinion. But the roofs are all completely different: T-shaped buildings. And even if I use these examples to find a general rule which creates all these different roofs, I still have no idea what kind of roof these buildings will have: more different shapes.

I guess the ridges are gotten by the intersection of the plane cut through the border edges by slope value (4''/12'' is the common value for single-family houses). Then we need to make the mesh from the input border edges and these intersection edges.
This is the way I have learned how to draw a pitched roof at the University of Architecture. So I believe this is how the roof tool in Revit runs to make the roof from any shape, not only for T-shape or Cross-shape,...

So I am trying to write a node that can do the same for any input shape and starting with a simple shape is the best way to understand how it works. Because I just think that if we can make a node for a simple shape, it will work for another.

But what you tell here about pitched roofs which you learned at the University of Architecture is not common knowledge. We are simply just Blender users (apart from perhaps some other architecture students), we might know how to create nodetrees but not the rules which apply for those roofs. Still I do not know why some of the T-shaped roofs have vertical sides and some are sloped. I don't even understand what 4"/12" refers to... 4 inches seems very small for a roof, and is 4"/12" not just 1/3?

Hi Gordon, please take a look at this illustration for the way the roof ridge was created Ridge Illustration. I hope this will be helpful for us to find suitable nodes.

If we can find the planes in green and pink by angle value, we will get the ridge from the intersections.

Is there multiple slopes, about the green and pink angles you are talking about ? I have a working solution but for only one slope. I assumed the 3 highlighted angles from your image were the same angles.

I've already tried a couple of approaches, but none of them are usable at the moment. I think the remaining option is to split the roof outline into segments, with each segment representing a single slope plane. It should be possible to specify the slope for each segment, but the challenge lies in the trick or order of slicing. It's too hard and complex for me right now. I'm really curious to see some answers here! TESTS

Boolean method:


Separate outline border and split edges.
Extrude edges and rotate to desired slope.
Instances in corners.
First repeat zone boolean corner instances VS extruded segments.
Second repeat zone each roof segment selects by raycast intersecting other segments, separate and create boolean volume from them, then boolean difference.

*4.

*5

result


PS: still there can be many errors, caused by boolean operations or just it is impossible to find and fix all situations. This could be extended with independet slope scale for each segment + should be possible to get rid of repeat zones just to move elements by its repeat zone IDs with some rule or IDs convex hull UV packing.

Hi Filanek, I just opened your nodes in Blender 4.2 and the result shows only a mesh of one edge. Is this caused by the Blender version? See the issue screenshot

yes, use the new 4.3 version

Your nodes work well in a variety of mesh shapes, Filanek. I appreciate your help. However, there is a minor issue when I apply the node with my imported mesh. Some faces overlap although using the node Merge by Distance (0.1cm) in your node. So the extruded meshes don't look good See the extruded mesh. I tried to use the Intersect (Knife) but it's not working. Do you have any advice for addressing this?

@Eric Nguyen, I uploaded some dirty workaround update, this should be just rough idea forum help, to make it work 100% for all situations would need a lot more time and I am not expert in geonodes and all takes me ages.... If you get some errors try to play with the values "RC subdiv" 1st and "scale segment" 2nd. good luck!

Diagonal procedural roof
Here is my solution to get the kind of roof you showed us, formed by diagonals extending from the corners until they meet. First, let's list the pros and cons of my solution.


Pros

Low vertex count : the vertex count isn't minimal, but it stays relatively low. For the 3rd example above, the vertex count is 126.
Flexible : it seems to work even if there are multiple extensions to the roof.

Cons

More-than-one island : the final mesh isn't composed of only one mesh island. Depending on how you want to use it, it can be ok or not.
Only one architectural style : my solution only covers one style, but it could be easily extended to offer multiple architectural styles.

Requirements for usage

The input geometry must be flat
The input geometry can be either only the border of the roof (no face), or be filled with face(s)
All angles on the border must be right angles



There shouldn't be any loose vertices on the input geometry. If some vertices can be dissolve (Ctrl+X) without changing the border shape, they should be removed



Edges of the roof should be in real world scale (ranged between 1cm and 100m). A few thresholds must be tweaked if it's not the case.

Nodes overview
The nodes are a bit heavy, and chances are that some parts can be simplified. It works by step, going from the base and up. You can see these steps with the wireframe view, each step corresponding to a ridge of the roof. For the following example, there would be 3 consecutive extrusions, each one finishing a roof part.


The number of iterations isn't hardcoded, it is expected from the user to enter a value high enough to build the roof to the top. A warning message will be displayed if there seems to be not enough iterations.
The slope is a mathematical slope : 0 for horizontal, 1 for 45°, $\infty$ for 90°.
This solution builds the roof from the base up to the top. Each iteration finishes one part of the roof.

You can see below the ridges that finishes one part of the roof, from the smallest roof part (part with shortest edge) denoted by 1, to the biggest part of the roof (part with longest edge) denoted by 7.

Steps
1. Prepare geometry
First, before entering the Repeat Zone, we delete all inside edges, only keeping the edges forming the outline of the roof.

2. Store edge length
I'm skipping the block named Delete unwanted geometry [...]. We'll go back to it at the end.
Then, we store in edge domain the length of the edges. The only edges that we are interested in are the most outward edges (in blue below). These edges will define the point at which the roof lines intersects (blue dots below).

For all other edges, we set the length to a big value. The reason is, the very first extrusion from the base stops at the lowest ridge of the roof, which happens to also be the roof with the shortest edge.
At every iteration, we extrude according to increasing edge length. The last step is the one that finishes the biggest part of the roof (biggest edge around the border).
3. Normals
Final step of preparation, we again delete the inner edges (like the very first step). Then we quickly convert to a curve to store the normal on the vertex domain.

These normals should always be perfectly diagonals, so there are only 4 possible values. They will guide the extrusion at the next step.

4. Extrusion vector
Let's see first how we can compute the extrusion vector. I'm decomposing the vector into an horizontal component (XY plane) we'll call $A$ and a vertical component (Z axis) we'll call $B$.

$A$ is computed from the edge length (with Pythagorean theorem) which serves to scale the normal vector borderNormal.
$B$ is computed by multiplying half of the edge length to the slope.
At each iteration, this vector will finish a part of the roof to its ridge.

5. Extrusion
Up to this point, no geometry has been generated. We only prepared the geometry, storing some useful values.
We can now extrude the border, then we move the vertices of the extruded part according to the extrusion vector.
Then, we move the current mesh to be perfectly sitting on top of the previous iterations (using the Bounding Box).

6. Clean geometry
Finally, let's go back to the block named Delete unwanted geometry [...].
At the end of one iteration (here it's the first iteration, building the roof for the smallest part in blue arrow), we get the following border as a base for the next iteration, highlighted in orange :

There are 2 vertices that we want to delete, here highlighted in blue. These points can be identified by having either 1 or 3 neighbours, whereas all other vertices have exactly 2 neighbours. That's all this block does.
Blend file
Feel free to ask for precisions if some parts aren't detailed enough. I haven't explain every node individually, but I can explain some parts if needed.


I’ll test your nodes on my meshs and get back to you soon. Thank you so much Lutzi.

Hi Lutzi, I just applied your node to my input mesh (imported from Sketchup (*.skp) file) but it seems my mesh does not meet your input requirements Mesh Input Issue. I have a lot of floor shapes that were created already  Input mesh and want to import them to Blender to generate the roof, so I do not want to remodel these shapes in Blender. Would you mind looking at this file and guiding me on how to address these input mesh to work with your nodes?

I tried to fix them by Fill Curve Node (N-gons) but it's not working. Adjusted Mesh Issue

Here is the blender file with my input mesh.
Blender File

You have faces with 0 area, in other words you have vertices that are on an edge but not correctly connected to it. I'm not sure what to advise here ... My nodes need the geometry to be clean. Also, it wasn't intended to generate roof for multiple houses. It may work but you will require more and more iterations for each new house, which I don't recommend for performance sake.

I’m sharing this out of curiosity—I came up with the same idea but approached it differently. I’m using a raycast node to measure the shortest length and a curve-to-mesh profile (with an even thickness Higgsas node) to create the roof. It currently works only with orthogonal topology, although there’s a fix in the node tree for minor unparallel errors. The file also includes another, unfinished boolean-based method. Still, I believe the proper solution should ideally handle nonorthogonal layouts as well.


very slow work in progress:


All mesh borders are orthogonal lines, Filanek. I hope your nodes will work with my mesh, as they are not quad meshes. I’ll get back to you soon. Thank you.
